# How do I control the data that goes into each data node in NDBCLUSTER

Tags: partitioning, sharding, ndbcluster

I am currently working with NDBCLUSTER.

I have the following table(*a dummy example, since I cannot disclose details about actual application, but the structure is similar*):

```
create table student(
 STUDENT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
 BRANCH_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES branch(BRANCH_ID),
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100), 
)

ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;
```

In my NDBCLUSTER cluster, I have:
1.

1. 1 management node
2. 6 data nodes
3. 3 MySQL nodes

Let's assume also, that I introduce 6 records in this table. My question is this:

**Is it possible to control the data(in this case, the rows) that goes into each data node/partition?**
If yes then how, and if no, then why not?